# Показы/просмотры вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация

Предлагаю привести к единому знаменателю обозначение количества просмотров вопросов. В данный момент одна и та же информация отображается с разными названиями.

Главная страница:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Страница с вопросом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На мой взгляд, на главной странице нужно выводить количество "просмотров", а не "показов".

Comment: предлагаемое слово длиннее. вполне может «поехать» вёрстка.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin можно отредактировать страницу и проверить. Наверняка "просмотров" не влезет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, у меня в «рабочем» браузере именно так и происходит, даже без редактирования — в браузуре шрифты увеличены и игнорируются любые пожелания уэб-дезигнеров по этому поводу.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это вы сами как-то настроили шрифты?

Comment: Может, нужно размер столбца увеличить. Или еще какие-нибудь корректировки внести.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну, да, в настройках браузера.

Comment: Как я понимаю, результатом обсуждения стало решение оставить все как было. Верно?

Comment: Если смотреть по голосам за ответы, то нет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, что должно произойти, чтобы был принят или отклонен вариант с "просмотрами"?

Comment: Необходимо задать вопрос, затем опубликовать несколько вариантов ответов и посмотреть как проголосует сообщество. Сайт мы делаем для себя, так что действует правило тоталитарности большинства.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, есть два ответа. Тот, который "за" набрал большее количество голосов. Будет ли замена перевода и правка верстки?

Comment: «Просмотры» в списке вопросов будет смотреться криво, это видно из снимка в ответе. «Показан N раз» в теле вопроса, как я понял, вам не понравился, то есть образовалась тупиковая ситуация.

Comment: Ну да. Если просто перевести, то будет криво. Нужно еще верстку поправить. Или разместить число количества просмотров по центру не получится?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Об эстетике:** проверил вариант с "просмотрами", вот что получается:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде бы входит вариант "просмотры", но почти касается края. Не хватает выравнивания по центру, наверняка его можно сделать, но я не умею.

**По сути:** соглашусь с автором вопроса, здесь именно просмотры а не показы. Показы - это метрика для рекламных баннеров, например. Вопросы же смотрят или читают - акцент на действии участника, а не системы. Это участник просматривает вопрос, а не система ему показывает.

Comment: Думаю, если выровнять по центру - будет хорошо смотреться.

Comment: Да, ничего сложного в этом не должно быть. Отцентровать и всё =)

Answer (score 2):

Как упоминалось в комментариях, «показов» – наиболее короткое слово для обозначения того, сколько пользователей просмотрело страницу. «N показов» и «просмотрен N раз» не конфликтуют между собой. При необходимости, можно заменить «просмотрен» на что-то другое (например, показан), но текущая версия, на мой взгляд, более лаконичная.

Comment: А "показан N раз" даже лаконичней.

Comment: Если возражений не будет, буду рад внести изменения.

Comment: Эти немного разные по смыслу. Показать (кого-что кому) - дать увидеть, представить для разглядывания, рассматривания . Просмотреть (что) - осматривая, смотря, ознакомиться с чем-либо. Пользователь, все же, просматривает вопрос.